# Why do I have a 'No such file or directory error' when I have created the file in the block of code?

Tags: python, csv, file-writing

I have a directory of csv files which I would like to read, extract the required information, and then save this as another csv file in another directory. I have defined blocks of code to complete the process I require, however I have run into a 'No file or directory' error when trying to test one file. As far as I can tell, I am creating the required file within the code, and so I don't understand why the file does not exist.

```
def writeFormPage(file, path):
    '''
    Input:
        Index CSV
    Output:
        Page CSV
    '''
    with open(file, 'r') as rf:
        reader = csv.reader(rf)

        base_name = os.path.basename(file)
        file_path = os.path.join(path, base_name)

        with open(file_path, 'w') as wf:
            writer = csv.writer(wf, delimiter = ',')

            for line in reader:
                url = line[-1]
                page_data = (parseFormPage(url))
                writer.writerow(page_data)

                time.sleep(3 + random.random() * 3)
```

```
os.chdir(PAGE_DIR)
demo_index_csv = '/Users/alexajones/index/2018Q4.csv'

# testing!!!
writeFormPage(demo_index_csv, PAGE_DIR)
```

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-81e495544fd6> in <module>
      4 
      5 # testing!!!
----> 6 writeFormPage(demo_index_csv, PAGE_DIR)

<ipython-input-12-ff5447b72e24> in writeFormPage(file, path)
     13         file_path = os.path.join(path, base_name)
     14 
---> 15         with open(file_path, 'w') as wf:
     16             writer = csv.writer(wf, delimiter = ',')
     17 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './page/2018Q4.csv'
```

I am absolutely sure I've made some silly error, as I am an absolute beginner, however I haven't been able to find it so far. I'd like to make sure the code works, as eventually I will be writing a loop to complete the process for all of the csv files in the directory. 
Any help will be much appreciated.

In response to answers from Barmar and Martineau; I had created the subdirectory further up in the program, 3 directories at once, though I have been having lots of 'these don't exist' problems with these. After your advice I decided to create each directory as required, as shown below, though I now have a 'doesn't exist' error in a piece of code which was working fine before. What am I doing wrong with these directories? As a side note, I need these to work on someone else's pc so I can't specify the whole path.

```
# Create a new directory to hold CSV files
indx_dir = './index'
if not os.path.isdir(indx_dir):
    os.makedirs(indx_dir)
os.chdir(indx_dir)
```

```
#Create new list to store URLs from csv files
sec_urls = []

# For each csv file, open and locate URL in line 4 and add to newly created list
for filename in os.listdir(indx_dir):
    if filename.endswith('.csv'):
        with open(os.path.join(indx_dir, filename), newline='') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            for line in reader:
                url = line[4].strip()
                sec_urls.append(url)
                print(url, 'downloaded and added to list')
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-281ad84b64c7> in <module>
      3 
      4 # For each csv file, open and locate URL in line 4 and add to newly created list
----> 5 for filename in os.listdir(indx_dir):
      6     if filename.endswith('.csv'):
      7         with open(os.path.join(indx_dir, filename), newline='') as csvfile:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './index'
```

Comment: Can you try setting  ```demo_index_csv = '2018Q4.csv'```. Since you are already doing ```os.chdir(PAGE_DIR)```.

Comment: This will happen if the `page` subdirectory doesn't exist. Opening a file for writing won't create the directory.

Comment: You can call `os.mkdir()` or `os.makedirs()` to create the subdirectory before writing the file.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your answer. I had created the subdirectory further up in the program, 3 directories at once, though I have been having lots of 'these don't exist' problems with these. After your advice I decided to create each directory as required, as shown below, though I now have a 'doesn't exist' error in a piece of code which was working fine before. What am I doing wrong with these directories? As a side note, I need these to work on someone else's pc so I can't specify the whole path

Comment: `# Create a new directory to hold CSV files
indx_dir = './index'
if not os.path.isdir(indx_dir):
    os.makedirs(indx_dir)
os.chdir(indx_dir)`

Comment: `#Create new list to store URLs from csv files
sec_urls = []

# For each csv file, open and locate URL in line 4 and add to newly created list
for filename in os.listdir(indx_dir):
    if filename.endswith('.csv'):
        with open(os.path.join(indx_dir, filename), newline='') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            for line in reader:
                url = line[4].strip()
                sec_urls.append(url)
                print(url, 'downloaded and added to list')`

Comment: FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-281ad84b64c7> in <module>
      3 
      4 # For each csv file, open and locate URL in line 4 and add to newly created list
----> 5 for filename in os.listdir(indx_dir):
      6     if filename.endswith('.csv'):
      7         with open(os.path.join(indx_dir, filename), newline='') as csvfile:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './index'

Comment: Don't put code in comments, edit the question.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks/ sorry. That makes much more sense! I have now edited my question.

Comment: Don't use `os.chdir()` if you're also putting the directory in your pathnames. Pathnames will be interpreted relative to the directory you change to.

Comment: So it's looking for `./index/./index`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Barmar this issue has now been solved. 
The code for the question that I asked originally has been changed to:

```
# Define a function to collect form page data and save as a new csv file
def writeFormPage(file, path):
    '''
    Input:
        Index CSV
    Output:
        Page CSV
    '''
    with open(file, 'r') as rf:
        reader = csv.reader(rf)

        base_name = os.path.basename(file)
        file_path = os.path.join(path, base_name)

        with open(file_path, 'w') as wf:
            writer = csv.writer(wf, delimiter = ',')

            for line in reader:
                url = line[-1]
                page_data = (parseFormPage(url))
                writer.writerow(page_data)

                time.sleep(3 + random.random() * 3)
```

```
# Create a new directory to save new CSV files
page_dir = './page'
if not os.path.isdir(page_dir):
    os.makedirs(page_dir)
os.path.isdir(page_dir)
```

```
demo_index_csv = './index/2018Q4.csv'

# testing!!!
writeFormPage(demo_index_csv, page_dir)
```